# Google Appscript WebApp Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

Does anyone know of an effective way of triggering a window refresh for a deployed Google Appscript Web Application using Javascript?

I've searched and tested variations of `window.location.href = window.location.href`, `window.reload(true)`, etc.

Nothing seems to work.

The only work-around that I've found is creating a hidden web-address link and using the `.click()` command to navigate to the same page (i.e. refresh), but lately, this is causing issues, especially because I now have to keep track of different link addresses.

Does anyone have a better alternative to this?

HTML:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Finance Mileage Entry</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <base target="_top">
  <?!= include("page-css");?>
  <a id="refreshLink" href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>?v=home" style="display:none"></a>
```

JS:

```js
function refresh(){
    var link = document.getElementById("refreshLink")
    link.click();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to refresh the Web App, you can just use [Window.open(url, windowName)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), like this:

```js
window.open("https://script.google.com/macros/s/{your-webapp-id}/exec", "_top");
```

#### Update:

You could also retrieve the script URL via [ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#getUrl()), instead of writing it yourself. To do that, you would have to retrieve this information from the server-side (you cannot access classes like `ScriptApp` from the client-side). You have to use [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to execute server-side functions from the client-side:

```js
function retrieveUrl() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(refresh).getUrl();
}
```

This way, `retrieveUrl` will execute a function called `getUrl` from your server code (`.gs`), which could be something like this:

```js
function getUrl() {
  return ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
}
```

Finally, when `getUrl` returns successfully, the [success handler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) will execute a client-side function called `refresh` (and its return value –the script URL– will be passed as a parameter):

```js
function refresh(scriptUrl) {
  window.open(scriptUrl, "_top");
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: thanks but this similar to what I use and would only work on either the dev or exec version since I can't change the link dynamically. Isn't there an easier refresh option?

Comment: @haby22 Not sure if that's what you wanted, but I updated my answer based on your comment.