# Functions are not being executed as intended. I expect the page to switch to 'setup' but that doesn't happen

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-apps-script

I'm creating a very basic log-in function on GAS HTML. In my HTML, I have a form that collects and stores user input with assigned variables (fn, ln, em, pw). It then sends the info to the sheet (which has formulas that verify the credentials) then a certain cell ('E2') will display "Found" or "Not Found". Then it will print the name in cell ('E1') if the `if` statement is false. This part does execute correctly, but the 2 functions, `render('setup')` and `notFound()` will not execute (regardless of when the `if` statement is true or false, neither one works.

I know the `render('setup')` function works perfectly fine in the `doGet` and when it is called in other functions.

```
function signIn(fn,ln,em,pw) {

  var url = 'www.somelink.com'
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var login = ss.getSheetByName('login');
  var fname = login.getRange('F1');
  var lname = login.getRange('G1');
  var email = login.getRange('H1');
  var pword = login.getRange('I1');

  fname.setValue(fn);
  lname.setValue(ln);
  email.setValue(em);
  pword.setValue(pw);

  var check = login.getRange('E2').getDisplayValue();
  var name = login.getRange('F2').getDisplayValue();

  if (check === "Not Found"){  
  return notFound(); // THIS DOESN'T EXECUTE
  } else {
  login.getRange('E1').setValue(name);
  return render('setup'); // AND THIS DOESN'T EXECUTE
  }
}
```

EDIT: HTML for the call `signIn` function.

```
  <div class="button" align="center">
        <button id="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" onclick="var fn = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
          var ln = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
          var em = document.getElementById('email').value;
          var pw = document.getElementById('password').value;
          google.script.run.signIn(fn,ln,em,pw)">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210355/discussion-on-question-by-jrob11-functions-are-not-being-executed-as-intended-i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want your web app to redirect the user to another HTML page after submitting the values, if some conditions are met.

You cannot do this by just calling a server-side function from the client-side: [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) is used to retrieve data that is not available on the client, but not to render a different HTML file.

What you could do instead is the following:

- Instead of returning a function (like `render` or `notFound`), return a parameter that can be used on the client-side. For example, you could do:

```js
function signIn(fn,ln,em,pw) {
  // Rest of your code
  if (check === "Not Found") {  
    return "notFound";
  } else {
    return "setup";
  }
}
```

- Your client-side function (which I've called `callSignIn`) can then pass this returned parameter to another function called `redirect`, thanks to [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) (this handler is necessary since `google.script.run.signIn(fn,ln,em,pw)` by itself will always [return `void`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myfunction...-any-server-side-function)):

```js
function callSignIn() {
  var fn = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
  // Rest of your code
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(refresh).signIn(fn,ln,em,pw);
}
```

- Next, the value returned by `signIn` is passed as an argument of the function `refresh`, which refreshes the web app with [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) if the argument is `setup`, all the while passing `setup` as a query parameter (`pageRedirect`), which can later be used by the `event parameter` (you can retrieve the web app URL dynamically from the server-side instead of writing it manually — see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60703455/10612011)):

```js
function refresh(redirectPage) {
  if (redirectPage === "setup") {
    window.open("https://script.google.com/macros/s/{your-web-app-id}/exec?pageRedirect=" + redirectPage, "_top");
  } else {
    // Whatever you want to do if "notFound"
  }
}
```

- Finally, back to the server-side, the function `doGet` gets called by the **`GET`** request from `window.open`. This function can check if there is a query parameter in the request via `e.parameter`, thanks to the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters), and render a different page depending on this parameter:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  if (!e.parameter.pageRedirect) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(e.parameter.pageRedirect)
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)
- [Web Apps: Request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)

Comment: I haven't tried this just yet, but this does appear to be exactly what my issue was! I'm about to look into it and try to implement it. Thank you!

Comment: Amazing! It worked perfectly with minimal tweaking. Thank you so much for taking time to explain it. And it is somewhat as I thought, issues between server-side and client-side. I feel so blind that I didn't realize that it would return a void when it expected a string!

Comment: @jrob11 You're welcome. I'm glad my answer was useful to you.